# How to get all images path of android gallery, no matter its Internal or external?

Tags: android

As far as i know

```
File directory = new File(
            android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "100ANDRO");
```

will get the image directory, but i am afraid if some phones have different directory then it wont work, is there any direct way that android api provides us to get all the image paths without hard coding the directory name as **100ANDRO** ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` which is only the external storage.For the internal there is `MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`. You can use a [MergeCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html) to combine both query results.

The main thing is to make use of the `MediaStore` class, which is a `Media provider` that contains data for all available media on both internal and external storage devices (such as an SD card). An adapter is used as a bridge between the data and the view.

For the implementation check out Demo [Fetch Images from SDcard and display in GridView](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/displaying-images-sd-card)

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList fileList = new ArrayList();

// Pass directory path to this function and it will return the files 

        public ArrayList<File> getfile(File dir) {
            File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
            if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                    if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
    //                    fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                        getfile(listFile[i]);
                    } else {
                        if(listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")
                              || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".png")   
                              || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpeg")
                              || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".gif")
     )
                        {
                            fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return fileList;
        }
```